# How to store and access big JSON files in MERN application?

Tags: json, node.js, reactjs, choropleth, mern

I'm creating **MERN** application which one of the main features is to present data in form of [*interactive choropleth map*](https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/). To achieve it I need to access GeoJSON files with administrative boundaries. These files contains set of GeoJSON fetures which properties are to be populated with data from database. **Each GeoJSON file is over 1MB** and it's loading time may strongly impact UX.

I tried to read these GeoJSON files in backend (`node.js` + `express`) and then populate them with data from database and send them back to user accessing certain endpoint. This approach works perfectly fine but it takes about 5 seconds to complete such request which is too long.

One the other way, storing such data on frontend (`ReactJs`) extremly impact loading time which is also unwanted.

**What is the best approach to store and access such GeoJSON data in this case?**

Comment: You can do what google does: split the file into smaller files and only load what's necessary at time of viewing.

Comment: It is not a solution in my case. Each file contains GeoJSON features that are required for single page. To different page I need to load different file. What I am wondering about is how to achieve it with as small as possible impact on UX.

Comment: 1 Mb of JSON is a lot of data. It is hard to believe that all of that is always needed. Besides downloading 1Mb over somewhat OK connection should take way less than 5s. Have you really pinpointed the bottleneck?

Comment: @EriksKlotins One file has even over 1.5 MB. Data in these JSON files represents Polygons with **really irregular shapes** (shore lines etc.). In these 5 senconds I include not only transfer time but also: MongoDb aggregate query and the process of reading GeoJSON file with `fs module` and populating it with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I end up doing is I defined specific endpoint for every file on my `node.js` backend.

Additionally I shrinked a size of every file (accoarding to needs) using *Douglas–Peucker* algorithm as it was mentioned by @EriksKlotins

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try to reduce the number of points defining each shape. The simplest approach would be to merge points that are less than X meters apart. There are more advanced algorithms to simplify shapes, for example [this](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/simplify/).

If you still need all the points for, e.g. calculations on the frontend, load a simplified shape first, and then load the big file in the background.

Chunks of points defining shapes seem to be a good candidate for caching. Look into that to reduce DB access/processing time.